# Combine Helm charts or leave separate?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, helm

I'm new to Helm and my first task was to recreate a simple pipeline. This pipeline is just:

PostgreSQL -> Spark, with ELK monitoring the instances.

Someone mentioned I may be able to combine all of these into a single Helm chart; such that when I run the Helm chart it spins up PostgreSQL, Spark, and ELK. Is there any advantage to this? Before I attempt to do this, is it a best practice or would it be better to keep each one separate?

Answer (score 0):

Using [Kustomize](https://kustomize.io/) you can combine multiple helm charts and make tweaks to them on the fly.  [JFrog has a tutorial](https://jfrog.com/blog/power-up-helm-charts-using-kustomize-to-manage-kubernetes-deployments/) for doing this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

It’s definitely a best practice in terms of maintaining k8’s manifests because with a single chart you have all the manifests in a single location and never have to worry about forgetting a specific manifest while deploying the application.

In the templates directory, write the configuration needed for all the services (Postgres, Spark and ELK monitoring) in *deployment.yml*, *service.yml*, *ingress.yml* as needed and do a`helm install`